# Check all fields with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a script that checks if a field is valid or not, if not it disables the form submit button and adds a red border;

```
      $('.date').on('change', function(){
                    var txtVal =  $(this).val();
                    if(isDate(txtVal)) {
                        $(this).css('border', '1px solid #000');            
                        $(".submit").attr('disabled' , false);  
                    } else {                                        
                        $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');       
                        $(".submit").attr('disabled' , true);   
                    }            
           });
```

Problem is I have multiple of these fields. If the user invalidates (makes blank) two fields, then corrects one, the submit button gets enabled. Because the script checks for 'this' condition, not all. I want to only enable the submit button if all with .date class are valid.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sM24d/)

Comment: `$('.date').on('change', function() { $('.date').each(function() { /* validate all date fields */ }); }});`

Comment: @pmandell I think the OP wants real-time validation.

Comment: You want to do validation but Class does it for ALL ?

Comment: Thanks guys, I did try change $(this).val(); to ('.date') but that didn't work, also tried each but not in the way Jason recommended, that's where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.date').on('change', function() {
    var valid = true;
    $.each($('.date'), function(i, v) {
        var $v = $(v);
        if (!isDate($v.val())) {
            valid = false;
            $v.css('border', '1px solid red');
        } else {
            $v.css('border', '1px solid #000');
        }
    });
    if (valid) {
        $(".submit").attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $(".submit").attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/sM24d/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/sM24d/3/

```
$('.date').on('change', function(){
    var numInvalid = 0;
    $('.date').each(function(index){
      var txtVal =  $(this).val();
      if(!isDate(txtVal)) {                      
         numInvalid++;
         $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');             
      } else {
         $(this).css('border', '1px solid #000');
      }                 
    });
    if(numInvalid == 0) {                   
       $(".submit").attr('disabled' , false);   
    } else {                                                          
       $(".submit").attr('disabled' , true);    
    }                                   
});
```

Here we go over each date field when one is changed and count the number that return invalid values. At the end we see if the count > 0 and disable the submit button if so.

Comment: Imagine 2 `.date` fields. Both are invalid. Then one is changed to become valid. This solution would not change the border on the valid field back to black (since there still exists an invalid field and `numInvalid` is not 0.